# Add Action to Custom Transaction Form in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, oracle, netsuite

I am trying to add a new menu option to the "Actions" menu on a custom transaction form in NetSuite. I am able to see my selection in the Actions Menu on the form, but am unable to trigger the beforeLoad function in my UserEvent Script to call a clientScript when the the Action is selected.

When I run the code as is, I get a message saying "beforeLoad" is not defined, although I am returning the function at the bottom of my script. I am unable to add an action to the 'Standard Actions Tab', although that seems to be where other actions exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

[image: NS Custom Actions]

```
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define([], 
    function () {
        function beforeLoad(context) {
            if(context.type == 'edit'){
                context.form.clientScriptModulePath = 'folder/clientscriptpath.js';
            }
        }

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad
        };
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to load the 'N/ui/serverWidget' module to use context.form